# Naming object in R from function input

Tags: r, function

How do I create a variable from function input? For example,

```
test <- function(var_name, num) {
    var_name <<- 2 + num
}
test(hello, 2)
```

so `hello` will then be 4?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Waht is your expected result?

Comment: Functions in R are not meant to alter variables values outside their own scope. This is not a good design for R. Function should return values that you assign to variables; more like `hello <- test(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
test <- function(var_name, num) {
    assign(var_name, num + 2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

test("hello", 2)
```

Here `assign` creates the varible `var_name` in  the gobal environment (you need to set the `envir` parameter to `.GlobalEnv` to do that). Notice that the `var_name` parameter should be a string.

Comment: or if you insist on `test(hello,2)` you can use `assign(deparse(substitute(var)), num+2, envir=.GlobalEnv)` -- but please see @MrFlick's comment above.